# In Cordova phonegap app, google map V3 getCurrentLocation method returns error on android Kitkat

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get current location on my phonegap app. I have added google api script as,

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
```

I have added required geo location plugin also.

Call to get current location is as below,

```
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locSuccess, locError, {
                     enableHighAccuracy: true,
                     timeout : 5000
                    });

        function locError(error) {
                  // initialize map with a static predefined latitude, longitude
                  // initialize(13.332222, 74.746111);
                 alert(error);
              }

              function locSuccess(position) {
                  initialize(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
              }
```

It works fine in android versions below 4.4. When i run the application in 4.4 and above it returns with error [Object Position Error].

Comment: after installation of app on device restart the device and try again. see if it works

Comment: you can use this geolcation plugin too http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation